# Exponent law for complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Exponentiation) states for $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$

${\displaystyle (z^{n})^{1/n}\neq z}$

Is this correct?

In general, the [exponent law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Rational_exponents)

$(x^a)^{1/b}=x^{a/b}$, $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$

for nonnegative reals $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$ doesn't apply to complex numbers. In particular, if $w=a/b$ is a rational number with $a$ and $b$ coprime integers and $w>b$ then $z^w$ has exactly $n$ values (unless $z=0$), so even the equation $(-1)^{1/2}=(-1)^{1/2}$ doesn't make sense (for complex $z=-1$ and $a = 1$) as the square root of each side of the equation has two solutions.

However, for $w\in \mathbb{N}$ and complex $z=r\exp^{i\varphi + i2k\pi}, k \in\mathbb{Z}$ the solutions to

$(z^a)^{1/b} = (r^{a}\exp^{ia(\varphi + 2k_1\pi)})^{1/b}=r^{a/b}\exp^{i{a/b}(\varphi + 2k_1\pi)}=r^{a/b}\exp^{i\varphi a/b}$

and

$(z)^{a/b} = r^{a/b}\exp^{i{a/b}(\varphi + 2k_2\pi)}=r^{a/b}\exp^{i \varphi a/b}$

are unique (i.e., independent of $k_1$ and $k_2$) and identical in real and imaginary part for all $z$. Doesn't this imply that the exponent laws above holds for complex numbers and $w\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: $a^{1/n}$ has $n$ different values, unless $a=0$.

Comment: @markvs Yes, that's also what is written above (I added "unless $z=0$" for completeness). But, $a^{m/n}$ with $m/n\in\mathbb{N}$ is unique no matter what $n$ is, and afaik that's what counts above.

Comment: "$(^)^{1/}≠$" - remember that the complex unit, $\mathbb{i}$, has 4 cycles instead of the regular $2$ for $(x^n)^{1/n}$ for $x, n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @Unexpected Confusion: Would do you mean with cycles. $i=exp(i\varphi+i2k\pi)$ is just a special case of what is describe above an everything applies to it. Afaik: The key point is, if the following is true or not: $(z^a)^{1/b} = (r^{a}\exp^{ia(\varphi + 2k_1\pi)})^{1/b}=r^{a/b}\exp^{i{a/b}(\varphi + 2k_1\pi)}=r^{a/b}\exp^{i\varphi a/b}$

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee: I'm aware thet the root has multiple solutions. What part of the argumenr after "However, for ..." is wrong. There should be a logical error to point at if its wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are missing is that you need to keep the argument inside some fixed interval $(x, x + 2\pi]$. Let's choose $(-\pi,\pi]$, i.e. the principal branch of logarithm: $\ln z = \ln|z| + i\arg z$, where $\arg z\in (-\pi,\pi]$.

The crucial thing to notice is that if $z = re^{i\varphi}$ for $\varphi\in(-\pi,\pi]$, then, obviously, $\arg z = \varphi$. However, if $\varphi \neq 0$, you can always choose $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $n\varphi \not\in (-\pi,\pi]$, so even though $z^n = r^n e^{in\varphi}$, $\arg(z^n) \neq n\varphi$!

Now, $(z^n)^{1/n} = \exp(\frac 1n\ln(z^n)) = \exp(\frac 1n(\ln|z^n|+i\arg(z^n))) = |z|\exp(i \frac 1n\arg(z^n)).$ This is equal to $z$ if and only if $\frac 1n\arg(z^n) = \varphi + 2k\pi$, for some integer $k$. We can write this as $\arg(z^n) = n\varphi + 2nk\pi$. Since we chose argument to be inside $(-\pi,\pi]$, we need to have

$$-\pi < n\varphi + 2nk\pi \leq \pi \iff -\pi/n < \varphi + 2k\pi \leq \pi/n\tag{1}.$$
Since $\varphi \in (-\pi,\pi]$, we have $\varphi + 2k\pi\in (-\pi+2k\pi,\pi+2k\pi],$ so $(1)$ can hold only if $k = 0$. We are left with $-\pi/n <\varphi \leq \pi/n$, but this is contradiction with our choice of $n$ to be such that $n\varphi\not\in (-\pi,\pi]$.

What we can conclude is that $(z^n)^{1/n} = z$ if and only if $\arg z \in (-\pi/n,\pi/n]$. This is always satisfied if $\arg z = 0$, i.e. $z$ is a positive real, but obviously not in general.

For example, let $z = i$ and $n = 3$. Then $z^3 = i^3 = -i$ and $$(z^3)^{1/3} = \exp\left(\frac 13\ln(-i)\right) = \exp\left(\frac 13(\ln |-i| + i \arg(-i))\right) = e^{-i\frac{\pi}6}\neq i.$$

Nothing changes essentially by choosing a different branch of logarithm, except that the whole thing becomes more tedious to write down. And, if you don't want to choose a branch and keep logarithm multivalued, then $z$ is always one of the values of $(z^n)^{1/n}$.

To reflect on what went wrong with your calculation, it's circular logic. You are using the exponent law $(e^z)^w = e^{zw}$ to justify the exponent law in a particular case. Just to be clear, $(e^z)^w \neq e^{zw}$ in general. Problematic part boils down to that even though $\exp(\ln z) = z$, it is not true that $\ln (\exp z) = z$ in general since $\exp$ is surjective, but not injective. Just like $\sqrt x^2 = x$, but $\sqrt{x^2} \neq x$ in general.

Concretely, $$(e^{it})^{1/b} = \exp\left(\frac 1b \ln(e^{it})\right) = \exp\left(\frac 1bi(t+2k\pi)\right) = \exp\left(\frac{it}b + \frac{2k\pi}b\right)$$

which is not the same as $e^{it/b}$, unless $k/b$ is integer. Note that $k$ is chosen such that $t + 2k\pi \in (-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: In  other words, the method to get all correct solutions of a composite function one has to introduce for the argument of each function that one uses in a composite function (e.g., for $z^a$ in $(z^a)^{1/b}$) the term $i2k\pi$ in the argument $\varphi$ of the complex variable $re^{i\varphi}$. So above, the correct way would be to write  $(z^a)^{1/b} = (r^{a}\exp^{ia(\varphi + 2k_1\pi) + i2k_2\pi})^{1/b}=r^{a/b}\exp^{i{a/b}(\varphi + 2k_1\pi)+ i2k_2\pi/b} \neq r^{a/b}\exp^{i\varphi a/b}$ with two $k_1, k_2$ for both of the functions $(.)^a$ and $(.)^{1/b}$. Right?

Comment: @Its_me, I didn't try to get all solutions. What I do is have some angle $t\in\mathbb R$ in radians that I don't know explicitly. It might be inside $(-\pi,\pi]$ or it might not, but what I do know is that there is a unique integer $k$ such that $t+2k\pi\in (-\pi,\pi]$. Then I can write $\arg(e^{it}) = t + 2k\pi$ for that unique $k$. Does that clarify it for you?

Comment: Afaik, you say I need to choose a fixed interval $(x,x+2\pi]$ for $arg(z)$ and the argument of a function of $z$, i.e.,  $arg(f(z))$. In doing so, I get for some $z$ contradictions. I'm somehow confused, because I had in mind that as long as I include $i2k\pi$ for complex variables in equations, i'll get all solutions. It think this is incorrect, because it seems I only get all solutions if I add $i2k\pi$ to the argument of each function within a composite function. Does the latter rule hold?

Comment: @Its_me, the question if $(z^n)^{1/n} = z$ or not only makes sense if you fix a branch of exponential $a^b$ by fixing a branch of logarithm. If you don't do that, then $(z^n)^{1/n}$ is the set $\{ z\exp(2k\pi i/n) \mid k \in \mathbb Z \}$ and $z\in (z^n)^{1/n}$. The "rule" of adding $2k\pi i$ comes from the fact that $e^z = e^w \iff z - w = 2k\pi i$ for some integer $k$. The places you add $2k\pi i$ don't really do anything since $e^z = e^{z + 2k\pi i}$ for all integers $k$. You are doing some mental arithmetic which is kind of on the right track, but I would recommend just using definitions.